# Error 404 handler in Django 1.9.2

Tags: python, django

I have got installed Django 1.9.2 and want to use a custom view to handle error 404. I am trying to do this:

```
# myapp/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url, handler404
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^not-found/$', views.NotFoundView.as_view(), name='not_found'),
]

#handler404 = RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('not_found'))
handler404 = 'myapp.views.NotFoundView.not_found_handler'



# myapp/views/NotFoundView.py

from django.http import HttpResponse


class NotFoundView(object):
    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls):
        return cls.handler

    @classmethod
    def handler(cls, request):
        return HttpResponse(u"My error 404", status=404)


def not_found_handler(request, exception, template_name='404.html'):
    return HttpResponse(u"New handler 404", status=404)
```

In other words, I overrode `handler404` with `RedirectView` initialized by the URL to my custom view called `NotFoundView`. But unfortunately it didn't work, I got the standard Django's error 404 instead of my custom one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your DEBUG setting set to False?

Comment: Yes, I have DEBUG = False and ALLOWED_HOSTS = [u'127.0.0.1']

Comment: Your view signature is far from default view signature. Try to define your custom 404 view with the same signature as default view and do your redirect inside your custom view. See for default one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/views/#error-views

Comment: I added the code of my custom view

Comment: See link above. I mean, define your view to fit `page_not_found(request, exception, template_name='404.html')`, and set `handler404` to point to this view. And if you need redirect, do it inside this view, not as a separate view as you have done.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but still not working...